# How to remove an entire line which matches a pattern

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

The following pattern matches an entire line, how do I search and **remove** these lines. If I leave a space in the replace string, it leaves a blank in that particular line, when I do via eclipse.

```
^[\t ]*<param name="logic" .*$
```

Comment: where/how did you used this expression in order to delete all matching lines?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know anything about eclipse but you may need to include the `\n` newline match in order to remove the line completely. Also - is it possible to replace with an empty string as opposed to a space?

```
^[\t ]*<param name="logic" .*\n$
```

Comment: I had to use \R instead of \n. \R is the platform independent line delimiter.

Answer (score 7):

To delete the line, you must also remove the line-break, not only the contents of the line.
So your Expression should end with \r\n instead of $.
Can't try it at the moment, so you will have to experiment yourself for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I found it much easier to delete the matching lines using bash commands instead of eclipse search&replace:

```
find . -type f |xargs sed -i '' -e '/pattern_to_find_and_delete_lines_containing_it/d'
```

[Credit](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000142590/comments/11086848176018)