# Remove whole (or multiple) line with search and replace in eclipse

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, replace

I've got about 200 Java files and I want to remove the following line within eclipse all over the 200 files:

```
public static final String ID = "@(#) $Id: LoginView.java 457 2015-10-26 12:52:10Z $";
```

The varibale content in this line is `@(#) $Id: LoginView.java 457 2015-10-26 12:52:10Z $`

How can I search for all of the lines and delete them?

What to do, if I have a commentary e.g.

```
//*****************************************************************************
//
//                            Copyright (c) 2015
//                            All rights reserved
//
//        The contents of this file is an unpublished work protected.
//
//        This software is proprietary to and emboddies confidential
//        technology of abc. Possession, use and copying
//        of the software and media is authorized only pursuant to a
//        valid written license. This copyright
//        statement must be visibly included in all copies.
//
//*****************************************************************************

//*****************************************************************************
//
// $Revision: 457 $ ($Date: 2015-10-26 13:52:10 +0100 (Mo, 26 Okt 2015) $)
//
// filename : LoginView.java
//
// contents :
//
//*****************************************************************************
```

The variable content is the last part and here it is the same: I want to remove the WHOLE commentary in eclipse in each file.

How to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like there are 2 questions here: remove the `ID` variable and remove the comments, is that correct? If so, you should split this question into 2 questions.

Comment: @Tunaki Yeah, I should split it, but I think they are really dependent. Yes I want to remove the whole variable including the value.

Comment: Like a regex find-replace where the replace is an empty string?

Comment: Click Search -> File... . Here in the file search tab you have everything you need, including regexp checkbox on the right, file name filtering and Replace... button on the bottom.

Comment: Would either do that with a tool like sed ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed ) or manually: text search for `"@(#)`, then click through the results and hit `Ctrl+D` to delete the line. Takes a few seconds each but should be faster than searching for the next few minutes for a better solution. You can also use regex search and replace, e.g. for `^.*String.*"@\(#\)[^"]*";$\n`: lines that contain `String`, then `"@(#)` and end with `";` (and a new line see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3725469/995891 )

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to match. What is constant, what isn't ? Also, do you expect to find that line imbedded in comments as well? There is a way to parse comments if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do text search by using Ctrl+h with scope as workspace then it will be searched in all projects in the workspace and will show in search result.
Now for each file do Ctrl+F and replace it.

If you are using Notepad++, then there you can search and select "Replace all in all opened documents" will replace it in all files.
Hopefully it solves your search and replace problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do text search by using Ctrl+H with scope as workspace like explained [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33847145/9240326), but you can use the replace within the Ctrl+H window of eclipse to achieve the deletion and don't need to use Ctrl+F.

To delete multi-line you can enable the "Regular expression"-Checkbox.

You dont have to write the Regex yourself, just mark the text and open Ctrl+H again after the activation of the checkbox.